# Emailed HTML Rich Text Column Relative URLs

Tags: email, url, richhtmlfield

Does someone knows another "fix" for this? I am looking for a simple way. And how is this in sharepoint 2010?

from http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/emailed-relative-html-rich-text-column.html

Scenario

> You have a list with a multi line text column with Enhanced Rich Text.
>   The item contains links from the current server. You are emailing the
>   contents of that column via SharePoint Designer 2007 Workflows

Issue

> The hyperlinks in the email do not work. The server name was
>   automatically stripped from the URL, making a relative path.

Resolution

> Workaround:
>       Add the following note to the field description notifying users of the problem and the workaround.
>           "Use http://TinyUrl.com for hyperlinks and images on this site.  This will prevent emailed relative links."
>       This works because SharePoint only strips URLs it recognizes as local URLs
>           These are usually defined in the Alternate Access Mappings
>       You can use any URL redirector
>
> Fixes:
>       Use Visual Studio Workflows and replace the Relative URLs with Absolute URLs
>       Intercept the outbound emails (on the SharePoint or Email servers) and replace
>       Use a custom Workflow Action that prepends the servername into the URLs
>       Use a different field type.  Try different custom Rich Text editor columns.

Comment: Is the url stored in the column as a relative url or is the url changing when being emailed?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the html  element to specify the base url to be used with the relative urls.  You would be dependent on the email client to implement the base element.